# How do I access my virtual environment when I go into Terminal (Mac)?

Tags: django, macos

I was going through a tutorial on Django for the first time and had to restart my computer.  After it restarted, I lost access to my virtualenv instance in terminal.  Can anyone help get me back in?  I can see the virtual environment.

[screenshot of Mac Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uduD.png)

[Location of virtual server on Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFvug.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this `$ Source path-of-virtualenv/bin/activate` this may works

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work for this specific situation.

Comment: How you create this virtualenv??

Comment: I created it using this guide. https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/create-a-blank-django-project/

Comment: @JoshFrazier If it didn't solve your problem, why did you accept the answer? This indicates to other users that they don't have to look for a solution for your problem.

Comment: I didn't use CFI Cli but I think you need found the path of your virtualenv , but  If you want start with django I recomend you [this](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/) Tutorial